# How to extend a templates xml:space="preserve" in Odoo 14

Tags: xml, inheritance, odoo, odoo-14, qweb

I am trying to inherit the `slide.slide.quiz.validation` in `website_slides` to change the label of a button of quiz page in eLearning. No errors are showing upon upgrading my custom module and the `website_slides` however there are still no changes. I already put the ff:

**custom_module > static > src > js > custom_js.js**

```
odoo.define('custom_module.quiz', function (require) {
    "use strict";
    
    var Quiz = require('website_slides.quiz').Quiz;
    
    
    Quiz.include({
        xmlDependencies: (Quiz.prototype.xmlDependencies || []).concat(
            ["/custom_module/static/src/xml/slide_quiz.xml"]
        )
    });
    });
```

**custom_module > static > src > xml> custom_template.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<templates xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="slide.slide.quiz.validation">
        <t t-jquery=".o_wslides_js_lesson_quiz_reset" t-operation="replace">
            <button  class="btn btn-light border o_wslides_js_lesson_quiz_reset">
                Retake
            </button>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

**custom_module > views > assets.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<odoo>
    <template id="elearning_assets" name="eLearning Assets" inherit_id="website.assets_frontend">
        <xpath expr="//link[last()]" position="after">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss" href="/custom_module/static/src/scss/course.scss" />
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//script[last()]" position="after">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/custom_module/static/src/js/slides_course_quiz.js"/>
        </xpath>
    </template>

</odoo>
```

`assets.xml` already included in the manifest file. I also inherited the `slide.channel` model.

**This is the original odoo template from website_slides > static > src > xml > slide_quiz.xml**

```
<t t-name="slide.slide.quiz.validation">
        <div id="validation">
            # existing code
            <div t-else="" class="d-md-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                # existing code
                <div class="ml-auto mt-3 mt-md-0">
                    <button t-if="widget.quiz.quizAttemptsCount > 0 &amp;&amp; widget.slide.channelCanUpload" class="btn btn-light border o_wslides_js_lesson_quiz_reset">
                        Reset
                    </button>
                    <button t-if="widget.slide.completed &amp;&amp; widget.slide.hasNext" class="btn btn-primary o_wslides_quiz_continue">
                        Continue <i class="fa fa-chevron-right ml-1"/>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </t>
```

I'm still working on resolving issues in my code, but I've reached a point where I'm stuck. I would appreciate any comments or help you can offer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer to the add-on extension.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="slide.slide.quiz.validation">
        <t t-jquery=".o_wslides_quiz_join_course_message" t-operation="append">
            <span t-if="widget.channel.channelEnroll == 'payment'">
                <t t-if="widget.publicUser">
                    Sign in and buy the course to take the quiz
                </t>
                <t t-else="">
                    Buy the course to validate your answers!
                </t>
            </span>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

Comment: Hello Yassir,
I did that also similar to your snippet. It seems like my js is not loaded properly. This was my code before:

<templates xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="slide.slide.quiz.validation">
        <t t-jquery=".o_wslides_js_lesson_quiz_reset" t-operation="append">
            <button  class="btn btn-light border o_wslides_js_lesson_quiz_reset">
                Retake
            </button>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>

Answer (score 0):

It is now solved. I still use the t-operation="replace" to change the Reset button and remove the t-if condition. My doubt is correct regarding the proper loading of custom js. There is just typo error in declaring in assets. I put the  `<script type="text/javascript" src="/custom_module/static/src/js/slides_course_quiz.js"/>` instead of `<script type="text/javascript" src="/custom_module/static/src/js/slide_course_quiz.js"/>`